# How can I access parent object "this" from its function in JS?

Tags: javascript

```
(function( $ ) {

    var TagHolder = function(element,options){

        this.property1 = options.p1;
        this.id = 0;

        this.init = function(){
           $('a').on('click',function(e){
              e.preventDefault();

              var id = $(this).attr('id');
              this.id = id;
           });
        }
    }

    $.fn.TagHolderProperty = function(options) {
        return new TagHolder(this, options);
    }
})( window.jQuery );
```

How can I access `this` object instance in line `this.property1 = options.p1;` from line `this.id = id;` so I can set the id property?

Comment: Create  a ref of `this` i.e. `var _this=this` in `TagHolder ` and then set  `_this.id = id`

Comment: or you can use ES6 arrow function, so you can replace the `function(e)` with `() =>` on click function.

Comment: jQuery binds element as context to all handlers. So `$(this)` refers to attached element.

Comment: @Speir arrow function is a bad option. It beats the `$(this)` feature of jQuery

Comment: @Rajesh it depends on your preference, in this case I think you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store a reference to this in a variable in the parent function, then use self in to reference the parent functions contexts e.g. self.id

```
(function( $ ) {

    var TagHolder = function(element,options){
       var self = this;


        this.property1 = options.p1;
        this.id = 0;

        this.init = function(){
           $('a').on('click',function(e){
              e.preventDefault();

              var id = $(this).attr('id');
              self.id = id;
           });
        }
    }

    $.fn.TagHolderProperty = function(options) {
        return new TagHolder(this, options);
    }
})( window.jQuery );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
self = this;
```

In your TagHolder function and then do

```
self.id = id;
```

In your init function